# What's the effect of spread spectrum on frequency- selective channel

Tags: digital-communications, fading-channel, spread-spectrum

In brief, we consider the channel as frequency-selective channel if the frequency of the signal is larger than then frequency of channel.

So, does using the spreading spectrum change the frequency-selective channel into frequency-flat channel? is that right? could you one explain the relationship of that in east way, please.

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In brief, we consider the channel as frequency-selective channel if
>   the frequency of the signal is larger than then frequency of channel

No offense, but that ought to win the prize for the least-accurate definition of frequency-selectivity I heard ;-)

What you mean is channel is frequency-selective if the **bandwidth** of the signal is larger than the **coherence bandwidth** of the channel.

> So, does using the spreading spectrum change the frequency-selective channel into frequency-flat channel? is that right?

No (and yes). As the name says, **spreading** the spectrum makes the occupied bandwidth of your signal **larger**. So ending up in a situation that the signal undergoes frequency selective fading increases a lot. The point is not the spreading, the point is that you spread the same information over a wider bandwidth and then at your receiver, you can **coherently combine** all these contributions. Therefore, after your combiner (which is probably what you meant anyways), the channel you'll experience will have a significantly lower probability of fading, since it combines the channel contributions over a wide range of frequencies with fade independently (frequency-selective) and thus are very unlikely to fade all at the same time.

Therefore:

- After spreading, your signal undergoes frequency-selective fading.
- After despreading/combining, your signal experiences a channel that is much more stable/closer to a line of sight connection.
- Since your frequency content has been "aggregated" you don't need to worry about frequency-selectivity after your combiner anymore (assuming all went well, e.g., you are perfectly synchronized).